# Why doesn't Node consistently recompile React code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

My colleague and I are building a React app.  When developing code, we start a local session with `npm start`.  My understanding is that after doing this, Node is supposed to automatically recompile the code after any code change.  However, I've just encountered a situation (and it's not the first time) when it clearly did not recompile after a code change.  The solution was to stop the session and re-run `npm start`.

I'd appreciate insight into when Node recompiles and when it doesn't.

Comment: That is 100% not Node's job. `npm start` runs "whatever is the (set of) script(s) bound to `start` in your npm "scripts" section". All Node does, and is supposed to do, is run whatever .js file you told it to run. If you need recompile, hot reloading, etc. you have to use additional tools for that. Some come with that built in, or configurable through plugins (like webpack), some are explicit file watchers to trigger things (like chokidar or nodemon).

Comment: Node on its own doesn't recompile at all. If you want that, use something like nodemon. If you're using CRA, `npm start` runs webpack's dev server.

Comment: Please show your `package.json`

Comment: `package.json` (Part 1/2) :

`{
  "name": "fleetpatch-ui",
  "main": "app/index.js",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.29",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-jss": "^8.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },`

Comment: (Part 2/3) :

`  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "prepublish": "npm run build",
    "test": "CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "wtest": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "flow": "flow"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },

Comment: Part 3/3

`  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^8.0.5",
    "flow-bin": "^0.101.0",
    "flow-typed": "^2.5.2",
    "jest-extended": "^0.11.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3"
  }
}`

Comment: Question: Which package is causing the recompile some of the time?  What package would you recommend we introduce to cause a recompile with every code change?

Comment: It has now been a few more days of me working with the same code using `npm start`.  Some above said that the basic functionality doesn't include an auto rebuild.  I don't think that is true.  My colleagued used the standard `npx create-react-app my-app` procedure and we haven't fiddle with `package.json`.  Yet, it does auto-recompile under many circumstances, just not all, which is the mystery I'm trying to solve.